# Supertest shows passing when it should fail

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

Here is the output from morgan

> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2016:23:44:19 +0000] "GET /temp HTTP/1.1" 404 17 "-" "node-superagent/2.3.0"

And the tests that i have written are

```
var chai    = require("chai");
var request = require('supertest');
var server  = require("../app");

describe("Basic tests", function() {
  describe("Check if server is running", function() {
    it("Root endpoint returns 200", function() {
      request(server)
        .get('/temp')
        .expect(200)
        .end();
    });
  });
});
```

The `morgan` is showing `404` code that i can also confirm by passing a function in `end()` but the test are running fine in mocha with no errors. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Try passing a callback function `done` to the test and doing `end(done)`

Comment: @mparnisari thanks, the async part. Post your answer will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the test is async and `mocha` assumes that, if you don't return a promise from your test or specify a callback function, your test is synchronous (more info [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)).

So, add a callback function.

```
it("Root endpoint returns 200", function(done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/temp')
    .expect(200)
    .end(done);
});
```